# Почему не удаляется класс по клику?

Tags: javascript

По клику на мою цель в консоли выводится сообщение, значит делегирование правильно работает, но тогда почему не удаляется класс?

```
<section class="drop-icons">
    <ul class="icon">
        <li><!-- close по нему должен происходить -->
            <a href="#">Contact us</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Whatsapp</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Telegram</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Позвонить</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

JS

```
icon = document.querySelector('.icon');
    icon.onclick = function(){
        icon.classList.add('change');
    }

close_icon = document.querySelector('.icon > li:nth-of-type(1)');
    close_icon.onclick = function(event){
        let e = event.target;

        if(e != close_icon) return;

        icon.classList.remove('change');
            console.log('y')
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас 2 слушателя и оба срабатывают, причем второй тот, который висит на внешнем элементе [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) спасет отца русской демократии, этот вызов отменяет дальнейшую обработку этого события

---

Так же поможет указать 3 агрумент `false` при добавлении слушателя через [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

---

```js
let icon = document.querySelector('.icon');
icon.onclick = function(){
    icon.classList.add('change');
}

let close_icon = document.querySelector('.icon > li:nth-of-type(1)');
close_icon.onclick = function(event){
    let e = event.target;
    icon.classList.remove('change');
    event.stopPropagation()

}
```

```css
.change {
border: solid
}
```

```html
<section class="drop-icons">
    <ul class="icon">
        <li><!-- close по нему должен происходить -->
            <a >Contact us</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a >Whatsapp</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>Telegram</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a >Позвонить</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Спасибо, вы спасли окружающих меня людей от дальнейшего моего насилия их, если бы не додумался до той строчки

Answer (score 0):

Потому что `e` в `if (e != close_icon) return;` - это элемент `а`, а не `li`.

Comment: да хоть "а" хоть "ли" класс не удаляется все равно

Comment: Класс удаляется и сразу добавляется. У Вас сначала срабатывает `close_icon.onclick`, а затем `icon.onclick`, т.к. первый находится во втором и на них обоих действуют свои методы.

Comment: @Kvilios могу ли я как-то предотвратить это:?

Comment: @Ученик *да хоть "а" хоть "ли"* - Прочитайте еще раз ответ. Подумайте.

Comment: @Ученик используйте `stopPropagation` в объекте события `event` или, добавив слушатель `addEventListener` с событием `click` и укажите отрицательный флаг всплытия (`bubbles = false`)